# Optimize query in sql

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone suggest someways to improve this function?I just want to display number in numeric when input is given in string(below 100)?

I'm just a beginner,so help is highly appreciated,
Thanks in advance

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbf_strinf_to_num (@word as varchar(50))
    RETURNS varchar(30)

AS
    BEGIN            
    DECLARE @number varchar(30)
    DECLARE @cropword varchar (20) 
    SELECT @cropword = LEFT(@word,5)
    DECLARE @namecount numeric(18,6) 
    SELECT @namecount =  LEN(@word+ ';') - LEN(REPLACE(@word,' ','')) 
        IF @namecount IN(1,2)
            BEGIN
            IF @namecount = 1
              BEGIN
                SELECT @number =                                                 
                    (
                      SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%ONE%'
                            THEN 1
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%TWO'
                            THEN 2
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%REE'
                            THEN 3
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%OUR'
                            THEN 4
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%IVE'
                            THEN 5
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%SIX'
                            THEN 6
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%VEN'
                            THEN 7
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%GHT'
                            THEN 8
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%INE'
                            THEN 9
                        WHEN @word like '%E%N'
                            THEN 11
                        WHEN @word like '%T%E'
                            THEN 12
                        WHEN @word like '%T%N'
                            THEN 13
                        WHEN @word like '%FO%N'
                            THEN 14
                        WHEN @word like '%F%N'
                            THEN 15
                        WHEN @word like '%S%N'
                            THEN 16
                        WHEN @word like '%SE%N'
                            THEN 17
                        WHEN @word like '%EI%N'
                            THEN 18
                        WHEN @word like '%N%N'
                            THEN 19
                        ELSE 0 END 
                    )
               END
            ELSE
                IF @namecount = 2
                 BEGIN
                   --SELECT @number = dbf_strinf_to_num1(@word) 
                   SELECT @cropword = LEFT(@word,5)
                   SELECT @number =                                                 
                    (
                      SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE '%ONE%'
                            THEN 1
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'TWE%'
                            THEN 2
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'THIR%'
                            THEN 3
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'FOUR%'
                            THEN 4
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'FIF%'
                            THEN 5
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'SIX%'
                            THEN 6
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'SEVEN%'
                            THEN 7
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'EIGHT%'
                            THEN 8
                        WHEN @cropword LIKE 'NIN%'
                            THEN 9

                        ELSE 0 END 
                    )
                    select @number = @number + dbo.dbf_strinf_to_num(RIGHT(@word,3))
                 END
              END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
               SELECT @number = 'Error! PLease enter valid number(1-100)'
            END
    RETURN (@number)

END
```

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server has not spelled format like Oracle `SELECT    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TRUNC (15321), 'J'), 'JSP')
FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Yes,that's really unfortunate for me.Hope they will add this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do so, is to create a table with two column.
First one containing the number in word and the second column the equivalent in number.

```
Create table NumberToWord
(
    NumberText varchar(50),
    NumberInt int
)
```

Once the table populated, you can make a simple join to get the correct number translation.

Another solution for number above 100 at SQL Central : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic794134-149-1.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.That's really very helpful, Instead of create table is there is any function which will auto increment the string in sql.

Comment: It will surely helpful for below 100,But when i try to get below 1000 it may not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table NumberToWord
(
    NumberText varchar(50),
    NumberInt int identity(1,1)
)
```

I just add identity to that and it works better